# Good book for mathematical modeling

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-modeling

Could you recommend/suggest a good book about mathematical modeling (Not advanced) with examples about classical mechanics, dynamics, aerodynamics, chemistry, electronics and etc?

Answer (score 9):

Your request is quite broad, so I'll give you a list of books that I own/have used and you should check which ones are interesting for you:

**Biology / Biochemistry / Ecology**

- A Primer on Mathematical Models in Biology - Segel, Edelstein-Keshet
- Elements of Mathematical Ecology - Kot
- Essential Mathematical Biology - Britton
- Mathematical Methods in Biology - Logan, Wolesensky
- Mathematical Models in Population Biology and Epidemiology - Brauer, Castillo-Chavez

**General Modeling**

- Introduction to the Foundations of Applied Mathematics - Holmes
- Mathematical Modeling in Economics, Ecology and the Environment - Hritonenko, Yatsenko
- Mathematical Modelling - Case Studies and Projects - Caldwell, Ng
- Mathematical Models - Mechanical Vibrations, Population Dynamics, and Traffic Flow - Haberman
- Modeling and Simulation - An Application-Oriented Introduction - Bungartz, Zimmer, Buchholz, Pfluger
- Modeling by Nonlinear Differential Equations - Dissipative and Conservative Processes - Phillipson, Schuster
- Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos - Strogatz
- Practical Applied Mathematics - Modelling, Analysis, Approximation - Howison
- Topics in Mathematical Modeling - Tung

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell exactly what you're looking for but Lin and Segel I think will at least have some of it and is a great book.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by advanced, but a wonderful book to model biological systems by Keener and Sneyd only expects basic understanding of differential equations and algebras.