# Reference request to study mathematical modelling

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-modeling

I'm interested in learning mathematical modelling. The course structure is appealing to me and just because of my interest I have already learned complete calculus and differential equations very well. Now I'm going to learn this on my own and I have the following syllabus :

[image: Syllabus]

Kindly suggest me a really good book so that my interest in the course don't decline. I have to master this course. I want to be be best at this because I have always loved solving such problems that the course offers.

I know that this is a broad question and depends on opinion but suggest me the book that you have used personally and found it good. Also suggest if there are any good video lectures available for this course (premium or free). Any suggestions of good classroom notes are welcome to.

Lastly I would like to say that I'm so much passionate about this particular course and I have never been so much  interested in learning anything before. I know that my interest level in this course can take me heights.

I have asked this question because I want to know everything about this course so that I can begin it well and give it a good finishing touch.

Also kindly mention all the pre-requisites for this course.

**Note : I have already tried to search related questions on stack exchange but couldn't find satisfactory result. But if you still think that a question like this already exists then kindly redirect me to that and close this as duplicate.**

Thank you.

Comment: Not to discourage you but can you explain what it means to "I have to master this course"? What does it mean to master "modeling of air pollution" and why do you even want to? I think any good book in applied ODE will have those "topics" as exercises.

Comment: @MSEisadatingsite with "master" I mean being really good with problem solving. I want my brain to think about everything in form of models. I find mathematical modelling to be puzzling and such things appeal to me. This is pure curiosity to explore what's inside. I can't explain you by writing because I'm pathetic at expressing myself via writing. Also what's this ODE? I can't help if I sound crazy to you.

Comment: Try studying fluid mechanics, (check out Batchelor's "An Introduction to Fluid Dynamics" and Acheson's "Elementary Fluid Mechanics"). It is a fairly mature field that is all mathematical modelling. For a more general list, check out some of the books from this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741132/good-book-for-mathematical-modeling?rq=1 (some of them are more on the technical rather than applied side). Mathematical biology is another good area to look for interesting and accessible mathematical modelling.

Comment: Haberman has a book called  Mathematical Modeling that looks decent. You could also check out Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos by Strogatz.